# camera.release() does not release the camera for next use

Tags: android

I want to capture two images, one with front and one with back camera on single button click. The code that I have written throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`, I know this exception is thrown when camera is already in use and we attempt to use it before releasing, but it can be clearly seen in my code that before capturing second photo I am releasing the camera using these three lines of code: `camera.stopPreview();` and `camera.release();` and `camera = null;`. So the question is that If I am releasing the camera before second use then why is this exception thrown? Please help.

**Code:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class PhotoCapture {

    static Camera camera = null;
    static int pic_number = 0;

    public static void takeSnapShots(Context context, int face) {

        SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(context);
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == face) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
                    camera.startPreview();
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator+"picure"+(++pic_number)+".jpg";
            File pictureFile = new File(path);

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.setRotate(90);
                realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(realImage, 0, 0, realImage.getWidth(), realImage.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**Button Click:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    PhotoCapture.takeSnapShots(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    PhotoCapture.takeSnapShots(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
      public static void takeSnapShots(Context context, int face) {

        SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(context);
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == face) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
                    camera.startPreview();
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    camera.release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```